# Semaphore Basic Operations

Tags: multithreading, semaphore, binary-semaphore

First off, please excuse me if this is not the correct place for my question.

I am studying for an exam, and this is the sample question that was given:

Problem given in a previous exam:

> Students decide to meet and go watch a movie. Students decide to meet and go watch a movie. decide to meet and go watch a movie.
>   After they gather together in groups of group_size, they go buy tickets. Each student student student buys his own ticket (becomes a customer). There are two ticket-booths (each booth has one clerk). If the clerk is available it will serve the next customer on line (one customer at a
>   time). There is only one line for both booths.
>
> Using semaphores and operations on semaphores, synchronize the two thread types: Student
>   and Clerk. There are numStundents (default 9) and numClerks (default 2). Consider that there
>   are no customers on line at the booth in the early morning. From the clerk’s point of view (it is
>   up to you) you can consider that both clerks were already at work or that neither of them has
>   arrived yet (when the first customer showed up). There are more customers than numStudents.
>   Give the type, initial value of each semaphore used, and shortly explain its use.
>   Don’t use Boolean variables if their use can be replaced by semaphores.
>   Roughly before the synchronization, a possible execution pseudo-code for the threads might be:
>
> ```
>    Student ( ) { 
>     arrive to meeting place // napping
>     group together
>     go buy ticket
>
>     buy ticket //napping 
>     watch movie // napping 
>    } 
>
>    Clerk ( ) {
>     get to workplace // napping
>     while(true) {
>      serve customer // if ∃ a customer
>     }
>    }
> ```

If anyone would help me solve this question, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: [Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Students+decide+to+meet+and+go+watch+a+movie.+After+they+gather+together+in+groups+of+group_size,+they+go+buy+tickets.+Each+student+buys+his+own+ticket+%28becomes+a+customer%29.&oq=Students+decide+to+meet+and+go+watch+a+movie.+After+they+gather+together+in+groups+of+group_size,+they+go+buy+tickets.+Each+student+buys+his+own+ticket+%28becomes+a+customer%29) -> [CS340](http://proto.cs.qc.cuny.edu/cs340/).

Comment: Why students go together always !!..

Comment: 1. They have to wait to group together 2. they have to wait to get assisted by a clerk

Answer (score 0):

As providing actual code would not really serve you, here are some few tips:

- You need to maintain a queue of waiting students, which will have to be locked each time a clerk decide to accept a student, and freed when the clerk is done selling tickets to the student(s).
- You need to make use of wait() to put clerks and students in "sleep mode", while your semaphore is = 0
- Think about the scenario where you can reach a deadlock (clerk never releasing the lock/ decrementing semaphore, etc)